# how do I read a socket stream dynamically with python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, urllib

OS: Windows 7
language: Python v3.4
lib: urllib

I retrieve data from a server using a REST protocol. The data comes back as a huge XML string.

At the moment, I wait for all the data to come in, and then I go through it and pull out the data I want. That takes a long time, and requires a lot of RAM.

I discard most of the data. So what I'd like to do, is read the socket input from another thread as it comes in. That way, I could pull out the data that I want. The XML is pretty simple and predictable, so I believe I could parse it myself before I get all the data.

I'd be willing to forgo urllib and write my own routines and directly read and write the to the socket.

Or maybe there's a better way, I don't know - I'm somewhat new to this kind of thing. I've used threads, and I done some socket reads and writes, but I don't yet feel perfectly comfortable with those things.

Is there an easy way to still use urllib but read the data from the socket as it comes in? And if not, what programming pitfalls might I be looking at?

Comment: Could you show the _few_ relevant lines of your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HTTPResponse` object returned by `urllib` doesn't cache everything by default. This is whats being done in `HTTPResponse.__init__`:

```
self.fp = sock.makefile("rb")
```

The read method reads from this socket directly.

All you have to do is call the `read` method of the `HTTPResponse` object returned by `urllib` and give it the number of bytes it needs to read.

Comment: Thank you. This is just what I was looking for.  (I think I'll skip the threading idea).